# "What about the privacy policy is unclear?"

Tags: meaning-in-context

On Stack Exchange, I found [a comment that says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175737/what-information-does-stack-overflow-collect-when-signing-in-with-openid#comment527140_175737), "What about the privacy policy is unclear?"

I understand it as "What is unclear in the privacy policy?" Is that what the sentence means?
Can I rephrase it as "What is unclear about the privacy policy?"
Can I generally say "What about *[something]* is not *[adjective]*?"

Comment: You should note that the "natural" sequence is *What is not [adjective] ... in/about/etc. something?*. You can use your "stylistic inversion" in some contexts, with varying degrees of acceptability. But you certainly can't use it with impunity - for example, nobody *ever* says *"What with you is wrong?"*. That one can only be expressed as *"What is wrong with you?"*. So I'd advise extreme caution when introducing this variant word order - particularly in the context of learners who might not even *know* the "standard" sequence.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What do you mean by "natural" in the first sentence of your comment?  The OP's cite is idiomatic AmE, considered mildly hostile--imagine "What about 'Get out of my life' is unclear?" spoken by one lead to another in a romantic comedy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, "What about the privacy policy is unclear" asks "what part/section/aspect of the privacy policy is unclear".  And you can absolutely flip it around to say "What is unclear about the privacy policy."

As long as the sentence makes sense, you can absolutely use the general construction of "What about [something] is not [adjective]". (Or "What's not [adjective] about [something].")  Also note, though, that in this construction the speaker is usually making the opposite point; ie. they think the privacy policy is perfectly clear, and don't understand what you could possibly see as unclear.

Some other situations where you could use this construction:

> Person 1: I thought you said this party was going to be fun?
>
> Person 2: Oh, come on.  What's not fun about this party?

Or:

> Person 1: You look great in that Big Bird costume!
>
> Person 2: Seriously? What about this costume is not ridiculous?

Comment: I think *What's not to love about homework?* (and the current favourite *What's not to like?*) are modern idiomatic usages that wouldn't be considered "correct" by many/most speakers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Good point; I didn't notice until you mentioned it that my second example didn't quite fit the pattern discussed in this question. I've changed it! :)

Comment: The replacement is so quirky I can't make up my mind whether *"What is not ridiculous about this costume?"* could even be considered "more natural" phrasing! :). But I will just say that Google claims 4480 instances of *"What is undemocratic about that?"*, but none at all for *"What about that is undemocratic?"*. So I do think there *is* a "natural order" for such constructions, even though there's no actual rule of grammar involved. There's nothing actually *wrong* in your answer, but I think my point needs to be made - particularly for learners.

Comment: So look, it's [Yiddish-English](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/whats-not-to-like.html) already & strictly for oral emissions, not for writing, except when rendering dialog, telling jokes, & being a conversational schlump.

Answer (score 1):

WendiKidd seems to have skipped your question regarding:

*"What is unclear **in** the privacy policy?"* versus *"What is unclear **about** the privacy policy?"*

The "in" is only about the content of the privacy policy - what is written in it. But imagine this dialogue:

> "I need you to sign this and have a question regarding the privacy policy."
>
> "Here, signed. Now, what is unclear **about** the privacy policy?"
>
> "I've read it a week ago and I'm pretty sure it's different now but I can't quite pinpoint the differences."
>
> "That's because the page layout changed, and now it's formatted in different font, in narrower column. That's all that changed **about** the privacy policy, and I can assure you nothing changed **in** it - the text remains the same."